# How do I upload firmware and configuration files via SpiDevice in Android Things?

Tags: spi, firmware, android-things

How do I upload firmware (microsemi) via the Spi port?
How do I then start, stop and check the status of said firmware?

Android Things Version: 0.4.1-devpreview (could not get the display to work on the newer builds)

Issue:  I am a hardware noob.  I have a python driver used for uploading firmware and a config file via the Spi port. My goal is to port this to Android Things leveraging the SpiDevice class.

The python version of the driver strips off headers and checks block size ect.  I'm not sure if I need to do this with Android Things SpiDevice.Write(buffer, length) method.

Once I have uploaded the firmware and config, I will need to start it.  In total I will need to upload firmware, start firmware, check if firmware is running and stop firmware.

I have started writing a SpiDeviceManager, and have naively began to flesh out the methods.  (see below).

```
    *public void LoadFirmware()
    {
        WriteFile(_firmwareFilePath);
        WriteFile(_configurationFilePath);
    }
    private void WriteFile(string filename)
    {
        using (System.IO.Stream stream = _assetManager.Open(filename))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                _spiDevice.Write(buffer, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }*
```

If anyone can point me at some docs or examples I would really appreciate it.

Also, if anyone has any advice about getting the display drivers working for the latest version of Things I could really use your help.  I have the device specs for the config.txt it just does not work.

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the firmware is used for a microsemi HAT.  This hat has microphones and 3.5 mm audio jack which I am attempting to gain access to.

Comment: Can you provide more resources as to the Python code and the datasheet? I don't know if there's any examples of doing this. You should expect the SPI on Android Things to simply send bits down the wire, so a direct Python port should work. If you have a logic analyzer like a Saleae, you can see what the Python version sends down the wire and replicate it. Re: display - We're working on it.

Answer (score 0):

The SpiDevice just sends the data along.

Its up to me to pack the bytes in there in such a way that the chip can make sense of it.

I am sifting through the data sheet to that end.

@Nick Felker, thanks for the info about the Android Things display. Cant wait for the next release to drop.